# How to add subdomain CNAME alias to other domain subdomain without redirection?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx

I have two domains, I own both.
domain1.com and domain2.com

on domain2.com I have a subdomain my.domain2.com which has an A DNS pointing to an nginx.

I want other.domain1.com to view content from my.domain2.com without redirection.

What I did is to setup a CNAME from other.domain1.com to my.domain2.com
But when I enter visit it it redirects to my.domain2.com instead of showing me the content.

Is this from DNS settings or nginx should be setup differently?

Comment: You need to show what `curl -v http://other.domain1.com` shows. Also the nginx logfile output is useful in determining what causes the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To serve the same content out of 2 (sub)domains just set multiple *server* blocks:

```
server {
  server_name other.domain1.com
  location / {
    root /var/www/wordpress;
  }
}

server {
  server_name my.domain2.com
  location / {
    root /var/www/wordpress;
  }
}
```

CNAMEs are not required, you can have two domains A record point to the same IP address.

Comment: acutally it worked with CNAME. It doesn't make sense to add server blocks, as I let clients setup this CNAME in order to use subdomain content as whitelabel.